# Methods to AutoRefersh RSS on Android?

Tags: push-notification, feed

Hello I'm currently new to android and I'm trying to make a simple RSS application on android.
I've put a together all basic aspects of the application as the parser and fetching the RSS through Http connection through ASyncTask as well as displaying the data in a listView.
How can I refresh the RSS feed (Google News) without starting the application ?? What is the best method for it (Push/Pull) and a simple explanation on implementing?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Implement AlarmManager which will start background service every specific time, complete action and go to sleep until further call.
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Option 2:
Use Google Cloud Messaging (server sends your phone data which triggers app/service to start) and do action. However I don't think this is required unless you want it to get new data when it's available rather than every specific interval.

Comment: Thanks as for GCM option is it possible for you to provide simple information on how to implement for Google news??